# Returning errors of Mongoose from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get error from Mongoose in the following format

```
{
    "errors": {
        "companyName": {
            "message": "Error, expected `companyName` to be unique. Value: `priStore`",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "type": "unique",
                "message": "Error, expected `{PATH}` to be unique. Value: `{VALUE}`",
                "path": "companyName",
                "value": "priStore"
            },
            "kind": "unique",
            "path": "companyName",
            "value": "priStore",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        },
        "companyEmail": {
            "message": "Error, expected `companyEmail` to be unique. Value: `pri@gmail.com`",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "type": "unique",
                "message": "Error, expected `{PATH}` to be unique. Value: `{VALUE}`",
                "path": "companyEmail",
                "value": "pri@gmail.com"
            },
            "kind": "unique",
            "path": "companyEmail",
            "value": "pri@gmail.com",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        }
    },
    "_message": "Client validation failed",
    "message": "Client validation failed: companyName: Error, expected `companyName` to be unique. Value: `priStore`, companyEmail: Error, expected `companyEmail` to be unique. Value: `pri@gmail.com`",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

I need to show at the client in a good format like

Errors

1. Company Name already exist
2. Company Email already exist

Should I be parsing the error at my client end or Node.js end? At the Node.js end, I can return appropriate error messages which client can display to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the errors object to an array of messages in Node.js by creating a helper method that takes the Mongoose error object, traverses the errors property and pushes error message to an array based on a pre-defined dictionary of error types and their messages.

The following function describes the above transformation and an example usage:

```
const handleError = err => {
    const dict = {
        'unique': "% already exists.",
        'required': "%s is required.",
        'min': "%s below minimum.",
        'max': "%s above maximum.",
        'enum': "%s is not an allowed value."
    }

    return Object.keys(err.errors).map(key => {
        const props = err.errors[key].properties
        return dict.hasOwnProperty(props.kind) ?
            require('util').format(dict[props.kind], props.path) :
                props.hasOwnProperty('message') ? 
                    props.message : props.type
    })
}
```

Example usage:

```
company.save(err => {
    if (err) res.send({ errors: handleError(err) })
}
```